# How do I use strided_slice to select all the element in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read the examples in document:

```
# 'input' is [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
#             [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]],
#             [[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]]
tf.strided_slice(input, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1]) ==> [[[3, 3, 3]]]
tf.strided_slice(input, [1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]) ==> [[[3, 3, 3],
                                                               [4, 4, 4]]]
tf.strided_slice(input, [1, -1, 0], [2, -3, 3], [1, -1, 1]) ==>[[[4, 4, 4],
                                                                 [3, 3, 3]]]
```

It seems like that I can not simply use `input[:,:]` to select all the element, instead I have to use the syntax like `input[:-1, :-1]`. However in this way `input[:-1, :-1]` , I will miss the last row or last column. What should I do?

I take an example:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.strided_slice(ph, [0,0],[-1,-1],[1,1])
input_ = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [3,4,5],
                  [7,8,9]])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(x,feed_dict={ph:input_})
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

I read a lot of material and I found that I can use `tf.shape(ph)`,let see:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.strided_slice(ph, [0,0],tf.shape(ph),[1,1])
input_ = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [3,4,5],
                  [7,8,9]])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(x,feed_dict={ph:input_})
```

out:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

However, if I want to get the result like this:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [7, 8]]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I having trouble understanding your question, but here's my attempt at answering it:

You can use the `x[:, :, :]` syntax to select all elements of an array:

```
sess = tf.Session()
inp = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
                   [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]],
                   [[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]])
print(inp.shape)

x = inp[:, :, :]
print(sess.run(x))
```

To get the last output you wanted, it's certainly possible with some manual  dimension calculations:

```
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.constant([[1,2,3],
                 [3,4,5],
                 [7,8,9]])
y = tf.shape(x)
bounds = tf.concat([y[:-1], [-1]], axis=0)
out = tf.strided_slice(x, [0,0], bounds, [1,1])
print(sess.run(out))
```

In general the Tensorflow slicing syntax follows numpy's slicing syntax, which is documented here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: This help me a lot. Before that I didn't know this operation below 
          `a = tf.placeholder(shape = [None,3], dtype = tf.int32) `

          `x = a[:,:]`

Answer (score 0):

The following would work as well:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.strided_slice(ph, [0,0],[tf.shape(ph)[0],-1],[1,1])
input_ = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [3,4,5],
                  [7,8,9]])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(x,feed_dict={ph:input_})
```

ipython notebook screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eilzi.jpg